# SQL fetch WHERE condition order

Tags: mysql, sql

..

Hi everyone,

I'm trying a way to show all my data selected with mysql SELECT query in a specific order*, and all this in one query (or more but the less is better).

- THis order is : first WHERE condition = first result that need to be shown

  second where condition = second results and this till the end of the WHERE Condition.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/78Uit.png

I hope it's clear.

Here is my code :

```
    $sql= "SELECT O.INTITULE, O.ENTREPRISENOM, O.TYPECONTRAT, O.DATEDEBUT, O.DATEINSERTION, O.REGION,
     O.FONCTION, O.ID_DIFFUSEUR, D.Id, D.MiseEnAvantOffres
    FROM OffreEmploi O join
    Diffuseur D
     on O.ID_DIFFUSEUR = D.Id 
    WHERE (O.INTITULE = ? AND O.REGION = $regions AND O.FONCTION = $fonctions AND O.TYPECONTRAT = $type_contrat AND D.MiseEnAvantOffres = 1 )
     OR (O.REGION = $regions AND O.FONCTION = $fonctions AND O.TYPECONTRAT = $type_contrat AND D.MiseEnAvantOffres = 1 ) 
     OR (O.FONCTION = $fonctions AND O.TYPECONTRAT = $type_contrat AND D.MiseEnAvantOffres = 1 ) 
     OR (O.FONCTION = $fonctions AND D.MiseEnAvantOffres = 1 ) 
     OR (O.INTITULE = ? AND O.REGION = $regions AND O.FONCTION = $fonctions AND O.TYPECONTRAT = $type_contrat ) 
     OR (O.REGION = $regions AND O.FONCTION = $fonctions AND O.TYPECONTRAT = $type_contrat )";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql,array($_POST['intitule'],$_POST['intitule']));

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {

       $html = '<div class="resultats">';

       foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
       {
           $html .= '<p>'.$row['INTITULE'].'</p>';
           $html .= '<p>'.$row['ENTREPRISENOM'].'-'.$row['TYPECONTRAT'].'</p>';
           $html .= '<p>Date de début : '.$row['DATEDEBUT'].'</p>';
           $html .= '<p>Offre publiée le '.$row['DATEINSERTION'].'</p>';
       }

       $html .= '</div>';
    }

    return $html;

}
```

and i want those result to be showed once, not twice or more.

I made several research but i really don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use a subquery that identifies the condition being met:

```
SELECT O.INTITULE, O.ENTREPRISENOM, O.TYPECONTRAT, O.DATEDEBUT, O.DATEINSERTION, O.REGION,
       O.FONCTION, O.ID_DIFFUSEUR, D.Id, D.MiseEnAvantOffres,
       (case when (O.INTITULE = ? AND O.REGION = $regions AND O.FONCTION = $fonctions AND O.TYPECONTRAT = $type_contrat AND D.MiseEnAvantOffres = 1 )
             then 1
             when (O.REGION = $regions AND O.FONCTION = $fonctions AND O.TYPECONTRAT = $type_contrat AND D.MiseEnAvantOffres = 1 ) 
             then 2
             when (O.FONCTION = $fonctions AND O.TYPECONTRAT = $type_contrat AND D.MiseEnAvantOffres = 1 ) 
             then 3
             when (O.FONCTION = $fonctions AND D.MiseEnAvantOffres = 1 ) 
             then 4
             when (O.INTITULE = ? AND O.REGION = $regions AND O.FONCTION = $fonctions AND O.TYPECONTRAT = $type_contrat ) 
             then 5
             when (O.REGION = $regions AND O.FONCTION = $fonctions AND O.TYPECONTRAT = $type_contrat 
             then 6
       end) as whichWhere
FROM OffreEmploi O join
     Diffuseur D
     on O.ID_DIFFUSEUR = D.Id 
HAVING whichWhere is not null
ORDER BY whichWhere;
```

(Note:  This does leave the ordering column in the query output.)

Comment: I'm having an error : "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'then 6 END) as whichWhere FROM OffreEmploi O join Diffuseur D o' at line 14"

Answer (score 1):

Combine resultsets given by different `WHERE` conditions using `UNION` operator.

Make an extra column `ordBY` and give it values according to `WHERE` condition which decides the sorting order .

```
SELECT <columnList> , 1 as ordBy
FROM tableName
JOIN<condition>
WHERE <condition1>

UNION

SELECT <columnList> , 2 as ordBy
FROM tableName
JOIN <condition>
WHERE <condition2>
ORDER BY ordBy
```

**Note**
You have to apply `ORDER BY` clause only at end **last** `WHERE` condition.

Comment: By the way, if `UNION ALL` is ok for your conditions, it is much faster.